# Is Application in foregroud?

Tags: android

When i start application from another one through

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app.app", "com.app.app.Main"));
            startActivity(intent);




ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcInfo = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

`Log.e("TAG", "runningProcInfo.get(0).processName "+runningProcInfo.get(0).processName);`

And I am getting Home application package

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

From the `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` documentation: "Returns a list of RunningAppProcessInfo records, or null if there are no running processes (it will not return an empty list). **This list ordering is not specified.**"

So, `runningProcInfo.get(0)` could be any process that's currently running, not necessarily the foreground one.

Comment: So, how can I check that my app in background? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> mRunningProcessInfo;
        mRunningProcessInfo = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : mRunningProcessInfo) {
            if(process.importance & process.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND==1)
            //process.processName is the process in foreground
        }
```