# Detect if an user is on the launcher

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to understand programmatically if the user is on the launcher (he's not using other apps or has not other activities opened)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it possible.
you can use the solution this links offers:

[Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)

if the fourground application equels the launcher - then you know it's the launcher that fourground