# How to check top running application with broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

I would like to check the top running application, I mean the one on the top, which the user is using. Is it possible to do that with `BroadcastReceiver` or it can only be done with `Service` implementing inside it a `Handler`?

Comment: you should use service for that

Comment: Look at this link. Is this what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Comment: Look at this link. Is this what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActivityManager has some method just like getRunningAppProcesses or getRecentTasks can be help.