# How to check phone is idle or not running any app?? in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, idle-timer

I want to check if android phone and processor is idle or not. Screen on/off is not sufficient for this case because may be music is playing even if the light is off and there are many examples like that. Can anybody give me any proper way to check this thing??

Comment: what exactly do you want to implement

Comment: "I want to check if android phone and processor is idle or not" -- by definition, if you are checking it, it is not idle, because it is running your code to do the checking.

Comment: Not completely idle. I want to check if user is not using his phone

Answer (score 0):

the CPU is never completely idle, since there are system processes being run in background and your own app is running as well. About the rest of the question:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List apps = am.getRunningTasks(99);
```

`getRunningTasks()` will return a `List` of currently active tasks, though I would not consider this method as a very reliable (please read the method's javadoc for more info). The int you pass to the method is the desired max number of tasks.

Comment: I can also get the number of processes but that does not fulfill my requirement I want to check if user is not using his phone

Comment: Not completely idle I know services are running in background as well as the system processes. I want to know if the phone is not used by its user.

Comment: @Ateeq please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service/5528441#5528441   if there's no foreground Activity means the user is not interacting with the device

Comment: but the example I mentioned in my question what if the user is listening songs the music player is not in foreground but still the user is using his phone.

Comment: well you could call getRunningServices() on the ActivityManager to get the services, however you'll somehow filter out the system ones