# Find time spent on a specific app(or more) in Android

Tags: android

I want to get the time spent on different Android apps by the user(ex: how much time was spent on the Youtube app, or Gmali app, etc).

I know that first i need to check if that app is currently running in the foreground(i know how to do that), but after that, how can i measure the time spent on that app?

I found getElapsedCpuTime () from the android references, but I think it can be used only to get the elapsed time for your current app only. If not, how can i use it to get the elapsed time for a different installed app?
Are there any other ways to implement this?

Comment: Have you checked this thread ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Comment: That thread is about checking/finding if an app is running on foreground. I mentioned that i already know that. The problem is how to get how long that app has been running.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) that provides many tracking features. Also you may get current system time when the application starts and when it stops/destroy and on subtracting these two values you will get the time. [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) also shows the device and time.