# Determine if foreground app is a satnav app

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to have my music player app launch when the user gets into his car. But if he has loaded a satnav (e.g. google maps) then I would like my app to run in the background.

I already have the code launch my app when the user gets into the car. What I'd like to know is **how to determine if some sort of satnav app is in the foreground.**

[This question explains how to tell what app is in the foreground.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service) But given that information, how can I tell if it's a satnav or maps application, without explicitly checking a list of package names? For example, could I find out what intents the foreground application can listen to? And are there any such intents which would suggest it is a satnav application?

Thanks

Comment: did you finally find a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is that connect your phone to the pc and monitor the logcat. Start the Navigation application and see what activity starts (from the logcat). Take a note of the package name.

Then in your activity, when onStop is called, start a service which checks the ActivityManager and sees if the Navigation application is running or not.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for checking logcat for packages etc. but I do not want to limit it to checking for one specific application (therefore package name). Is there any way of checking if the app is *any* maps app?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I would guess all the navigation apps have map(s) or navigation keyword in them