# Listen when App is in Background

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a Service running and i want the service to be informed when certain apps get opened and closed / stopped. I think the start of an App is possible to listen on, but what about the start/resume and the stop ?

Comment: I believe this is impossible?  It would be a breach of security on the device.

Comment: from logs may be u can figure out ..by adb logcat | grep "ActivityManager" actually tell which is current activity in android..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check the foreground application?

See this SO thread: [Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)

When the application changes, you know that the app has been stopped/paused.

Comment: this is already really nice, though i have to check manually instead of listening, but if there is no other solution to it, this will be it

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to do it, as it would be a security issue to be able to read other apps state.