# How to get the most recent application(not the top activity of my own app): in android API 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I was  using the following code to find the activity curently in foreground

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
```

untill 4.4.4 . Now in API 21 getRunningTasks() is deprecated. My requirement is to find the current foreground application running.

Not the top activity of my own app but the current activity running

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nikola the link you shared talks about "top activity of my own app" but I'm looking for any activity ... it may or may not  be of my app

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)