# Cannot get foreground activity name in Android Lollipop 5.0 only

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-manager

I use the following code to get the activity name of the foreground app in the variable **foregroundTaskPackageName**. It works on all OS versions between 4.1 to 4.4, but does not work in Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Can anyone help with what has changed in 5.0 Lollipop? In Lollipop - the text I get for **foregroundTaskPackageName** is just 'Launcher3'. I am using the Genymotion Emulator.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0); // get
                                                                        // list
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // running
                                                                        // tasks
String foregroundTaskAppName = null;
String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity
                .getPackageName();
```

Comment: I was wondering if you were able to retrieve the topActivity with the new UsageStatsManager for Android L. If yes please let me know how. A sample code would be useful also. Thanks.

Comment: @user3144836 : are you able to find the way to get TopActivity?

Comment: @venkat : Nope. Haven't figured how to do that yet in Android 5.0 lollipop

Comment: Answered the same in this thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service/30778294#30778294

Please have a look.

Comment: I solved this problem; see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36086106/2217336

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the new `UsageStatsManager` and call its `queryUsageStats` method to get the history of activities launched.
Please note that the user will be required to provide access to usage stat on the device settings at Security->Apps with usage access.

Links:

[`UsageStatsManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)

[`queryUsageStats` method documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryUsageStats(int,%20long,%20long))

Answer (score 29):

This works for me on Lollipop (21):

```
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    Log.i("current_app",tasks.get(0).processName);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the top activity using this approach?

Comment: Because i wish to get notified for an exact activity from an application.

Comment: @venekat sry but this only gets the current running application  and not the activity

Comment: FYI This behavior is not guaranteed in the API. See the note about the ordering being unspecified. Even if it works now, this behavior could break in the future. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()

Comment: This only returns your own packagename, tested on Motorolla MotoX

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi the last Code line returns the current running process. In your case your own package name if your current Application is your package. the tasks object contains all running processes look into the tasks object and you will see all running processes

Answer (score 8):

you can use below code and get the current foreground activity package name.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // intentionally using string value as Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE was
        // strangely only added in API 22 (LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        @SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant")
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                        time - 1000 * 1000, time);
                if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),
                                usageStats);
                    }
                    if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        currentApp = mySortedMap.get(
                                mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    }
                }
    } else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am
                        .getRunningAppProcesses();
                currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }
```

> Add these permissions in to Manifest file (first one is for < API 21, second one for >= API 21).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: did you run this code in your app?Because I am not able to find UsageStatsManager. can you share your java file or code?

Comment: @nitishpatel `UsageStatsManager` only exists on API 21 and above.

Comment: This works for foreground package name, but what about the Activity class name?

Comment: @user1118764 Did you find any way to get the activity class name ? Please let me know

Answer (score 4):

As per [getRunningTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) docs:

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. **As of LOLLIPOP, this
>   method is no longer available to third party applications**: the
>   introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person
>   information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still
>   return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks,
>   and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be
>   sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

an available but not best way is to use accessibility.

Declare an accessibility service in AndroidManifest xml file

```
<service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>
```

accessibility_service_config.xml file

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_desc"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

store the activity name when window state changed

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService{
    public static String sActivityName;
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED){
            Log.d("activitytest", "onAccessibilityEvent with window state changed");
            sActivityName = event.getClassName().toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The disadvantage is that you need to let users enable your accessibility service in Settings.

Answer (score 2):

i have created a class that uses `/system/bin/toolbox` command to identify processes and then identifies visible application.
Need to add identifies system apps with no UI and android launchers.

[ProcessManager.java](https://github.com/rukmaldias/AndroidUtils/blob/master/ProcessManager.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static boolean isForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if(tasks.isEmpty())
        return false;

    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo task : tasks) {
        if(context.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.processName)){
            return task.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```