# How to get running application activity Name in android 5.0(L)?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using the following code to get the current running activity name in android.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);            
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
                .getRunningTasks(1);

ComponentName componentInfo = alltasks.get(0).topActivity;
componentInfo.getClassName();

System.out.println("Current:"+componentInfo.getClassName());
```

This is working fine in all the versions below android `5.0`. But in Android 5.0 it **always returning the launcher activity**.

Please any one help in this because I want to make run the application in all android versions.

Comment: for me this does not work fine for version below 5.0 and raises java.lang.SecurityException. See here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350328/global-class-to-register-listeners-for-all-the-activities-in-android. Please suggest

Comment: For everybody looking for an answer, I recommend to read that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag

Comment: try this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066231/how-to-gettopactivity-name-or-get-current-running-application-package-name-in-lo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prior to Android L your code will work, but from Android L onward getRunningTask will not work. You have to use getAppRunningProcess.

Check this code below -

```
public class DetectCalendarLaunchRunnable implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
  String[] activePackages;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    activePackages = getActivePackages();
  } else {
    activePackages = getActivePackagesCompat();
  }
  if (activePackages != null) {
    for (String activePackage : activePackages) {
      if (activePackage.equals("com.google.android.calendar")) {
        //Calendar app is launched, do something
      }
    }
  }
  mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}

String[] getActivePackagesCompat() {
  final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
  final ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
  final String[] activePackages = new String[1];
  activePackages[0] = componentName.getPackageName();
  return activePackages;
}

String[] getActivePackages() {
  final Set<String> activePackages = new HashSet<String>();
  final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfos) {
    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
      activePackages.addAll(Arrays.asList(processInfo.pkgList));
    }
  }
  return activePackages.toArray(new String[activePackages.size()]);
}
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Worked fine. You are the lifesaver of me. Thanks a lot @Ashish Tamrakar

Comment: @AshishTamrakar , Here by using ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo calss we are getting only packages names but not along with activity names. so change answer according to question.

Comment: what if I want to get the name of activity class instead of the package?

Comment: I'm using this code in a Android 5.1.1 and always getting the launcher activity again... doors are closed again?

Comment: This will NO LONGER work with Update 5.1.1, they decided to silently remove the support. The method will now only return your own package processes.

Comment: This answer show how to get the current application, but not the current activity according to question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
String packageName = "";
String className = "";

UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

if (usageStatsManager != null)
{
   UsageEvents queryEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000, System.currentTimeMillis());

   if (queryEvents != null) 
   {
      UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();

      while (queryEvents.hasNextEvent()) 
      {
          UsageEvents.Event eventAux = new UsageEvents.Event();
          queryEvents2.getNextEvent(eventAux);

          if (eventAux.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND)
          {
              event = eventAux;
          }
      }

      packageName = event.getPackageName();
      className = event.getClassName();
   }
}
```

You need the android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

Or you can do:

```
pm grant com.your.package android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087675/cannot-get-foreground-activity-name-in-android-lollipop-5-0-only).

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in Android 5.0: it is not possible to get the top most activity, nor is it possible get any callback when a new application/activity is launched in realtime.

[methods deplicated in 5.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))

Comment: Well, your link actually provides the answer? So "it is not possible" is simply not true. Its more: "depends on..".

Comment: It is possible to get a callback if you implement an Accessibility Service.

Comment: can you point to an example on how to use AccessibilityService to get a callback?