# Get The Current Foreground Activity Name And The Package Name In Lollipop

Tags: android

there are lots of question about this topic but all are only about getting the package name. 
what i want is get the activity name.

currently i am using the below method to get the activity name but as you know ActivityManager.getRunningTasks is now deprecated, so is there an alternative way to get this or i should stick with this and it won't do any harm?

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);   //deprecated 


//taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName() //this gets the activity name
```

Comment: Did you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625936/getrunningtasks-doesnt-work-in-android-l

Comment: yes i did try that method and was able to get the package name, but was not able to get the current foreground activity name

Comment: You can refer [How to get running application activity Name in android 5.0(L)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689276/how-to-get-running-application-activity-name-in-android-5-0l)

Answer (score 0):

Is Late, but maybe this can help someone else:

```
String activityName = (String) activity.getTitle();
```