# How to detect the running activity of another app in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to detect when another app is running in foreground?

Is it possible to detect the specific activity of the app that is currently in the foreground?

For example if I have a package id com.netflix.mediaclient I need to detect when com.netflix.mediaclient.MediaPlayer is active.

Comment: In oncreate Of the activity you can always get class name  by getLocalClassName().

Comment: did you saw this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27689352/2704821
I think this is what you want

Answer (score -1):

Hiii

```
public class DetectCalendarLaunchRunnable implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
  String[] activePackages;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    activePackages = getActivePackages();
  } else {
    activePackages = getActivePackagesCompat();
  }
  if (activePackages != null) {
    for (String activePackage : activePackages) {
      if (activePackage.equals("com.google.android.calendar")) {
        //Calendar app is launched, do something
      }
    }
  }
  mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}

String[] getActivePackagesCompat() {
  final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
  final ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
  final String[] activePackages = new String[1];
  activePackages[0] = componentName.getPackageName();
  return activePackages;
}

String[] getActivePackages() {
  final Set<String> activePackages = new HashSet<String>();
  final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfos) {
    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
      activePackages.addAll(Arrays.asList(processInfo.pkgList));
    }
  }
  return activePackages.toArray(new String[activePackages.size()]);
}
}
```

This can give you running activity name