# In android - How to prevent Firebase push notification when app is in foreground?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made a push notification service in firebase and sending data notifications and receiving it in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` very well,

I am well aware when to send which type of notifications and that's why I have used data notifications to get it when the app is killed.

But in my case, **I do not want to send any notification when app is in Foreground mode, as  `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` will always get called when the app is in Foreground mode.**

How to prevent this situation?

My notification format is this..

```
{
   "to" : "cGPhwcLbe5Y:APA91bFVAR6n9GxbDBovzd8X9nMBvKZ4Z098FzmkMGGUAuMhdps4uEof8mppUh7vrFTAsdFGzyurHa4gQ1nWgP-ncaN53ZtHziLi8YdHMEOGvtx6pA7ttCY5QhE5XKdFZ2QfX",
   "data" : {
    "message":"hi"
 }

}
```

Comment: @AL. please provide appropriate link man

Comment: whoops. Sorry. Copied the wrong link. Here it is -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/8489993/4625829

Comment: delete that confusing comment @AL. and second thing have you seen comments on that answer? I have already checked that answer but it's not an efficient way, also GET_TASKS permission is deprecated above api 21, and it is necessary to make that answer work

Comment: I referenced it for the idea. Because unless you find a way to do something similar to it, I don't think there is any other way for you to *prevent* showing notifications.

Comment: @TapanHP bro understand what others are trying to explain you instead of what already in your mind.. AL's suggested link will also work after API 21

Comment: but after API 21 GET_TASKS permission is deprecated @SanketKachhela

Comment: both suggested answer aren't using that permission.

Comment: @AL. can we do something from Firebase side, like is there any method that can handle this?

Comment: @SanketKachhela well the same link provided another answer could be the solution, can you check it for me?

Comment: So which way will preferable more? yours provided link or Al.'s ? @SanketKachhela

Comment: Nope. You're well aware that `onMessageReceived()` will always be called for `data`-only payloads even when the app is in foreground/background. This has to be checked on client side. Unless you can check if user is *online* (app foreground), then don't send push notifications for a while. Only if you've determined if the user is maybe *idle/offline*, that's when you send push notifications.

Comment: okay cool, I will check out the link you have provided @AL.

Comment: No worries. Good luck. If ever you find a workaround, add it in as answer for the community to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 2 different type of message you can send from your server.

[image]

Where **Notification message** is handle by **firebase** itself.

**Data message** is custom payload, where you need to manage notification from your self.

so you need to use data key in your server script.

and just check that which app is running in top stack from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27689352/942224

```
private boolean isAppInForground(Context context, String packageName){
  String[] activePackages;
  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   activePackages = getActivePackages(am);

   if (activePackages != null) {
       return activePackages[0].equals(packagName)
   }
    return false;
}



private String[] getActivePackages(ActivityManager mActivityManager) {
final Set<String> activePackages = new HashSet<>();
final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfos) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                activePackages.addAll(Arrays.asList(processInfo.pkgList));
            }
        }
        return activePackages.toArray(new String[activePackages.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't i told that i am well aware about it? I am already sending data notification with a message parameter in data

Comment: but the thing is i don't want to send notification in Foreground mode

Comment: @TapanHP yeah initially didn't read that.. see edited answer.

Comment: Seen but your solution will not work after 5.1.1 @Sanket

Comment: where it's going to be break?

Comment: There is clearly condition for lolipop and prior version. so permission should not be any issue. hope you can understand..

Comment: Okay great i will check both of them, really appreciate your help, but please update your answer to make things clear for others :) @Sanket

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are delivered to your `onMessageReceived` callback only when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center. If you want to prevent that `onMessageReceived` is being called when your app is in the foreground. just get rid of `FirebaseMessagingService` from your app.

Check the docuemnt: 
[Send your First Message to a Backgrounded App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message)