# Get foreground activity from package name?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to get running activity name (Foreground activity name) from package name as you all know that we can get currently running activity name
**via this line**

```
mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName()
```

but this work only bellow android  5.0 i need same thing in above 5.0

i am able to get current package name but not activity

Answer (score 6):

security is enhanced from android Lollipop; see this article for more details: [getAppTask](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-5-api-changes-getapptasks/)

You could get foreground activities via UsageStats class; first, you have to add this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
                                    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

and this declaration:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="your_application_package">
```

This will disable warning that permission is system level and will not be granted to third-party apps. User of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

So, in onCreate() method of your MainActivity, check if user granted this permission

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if(!hasPermission()){
            startActivityForResult(
                    new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS),
                    Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS);
        }
    }
```

And if no, ask user to enable it:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS){
        if (!hasPermission()){
            startActivityForResult(
                    new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS),
                    Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS);
        }
    }
}
private boolean hasPermission() {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager)
            getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = 0;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
    }
    return mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
}
```

Finally, here's a snippet to put in a background service, that gives you package name of current foreground activites:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private String getUsageStatsForegroundActivityName() {


    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long beginTime = endTime - 1000 * 60;

    // result
    String topActivity = null;

    // We get usage stats for the last minute
    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, beginTime, endTime);

    // Sort the stats by the last time used
    if (stats != null) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
            topActivity = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            logger.info("topActivity: " + topActivity);
        }
    }
    if (topActivity != null)
        return topActivity;
    else
        return Constant.ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND;

}
```

Comment: how to use hasPermission()

Comment: I updated my answer and added hasPermission() method

Comment: Could you post whole class. I found some error from your class as  `Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`

Comment: Please note that the user will be required to provide access to usage stat on the device settings at Security->Apps with usage access. Do you know how to automatic turn on this mode. If not turn on the setting, your code will not works.