# How to pull running services in Android 8/O (Oreo) after getRunningservices(ActivityManager) deprecated

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to find a workaround to the getRunningServices method that is deprecated in Android 8 (O). I am interested in finding, from a background service, if a specific service is running. (I am not the owner of the service that I am interested in finding).

Is there any workaround for that method? How are other apps pulling those details in Android 8 like Antivirus or Performance Booster Apps?

Comment: Maybe this answer is similar to what you are asking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34262531/2607567

Answer (score 0):

> pull running services in Android 8/O (Oreo) after getRunningservices(ActivityManager) deprecated

The short answer is NO.

As the [getRunningServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningServices) document said:

> As of Build.VERSION_CODES.O, this method is no longer available to third party applications. For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services.

It is said here that the method will not be available for third-party applications.

> **Notes:  this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**