# GcmListenerService is not working

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

If I have both notification and data attributes in the payload, there is no call being made to GcmListenerService. Anyone knows why? The current behavior is given below.
1. Payload contains notification only: GCM takes care of notif display. No call to listener
2. Payload contains data only: No default notif display. But GcmListenerService is invoked.
3. Payload contains both notification and data: GCM takes care of notif display. No call to listener.

I need the listenerservice to be called to handle the scenarios when app is active and in foreground. Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

checkout [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service), it will help you to check, whether the application is in background or foreground. And then operate accordingly.

Tell me if i misunderstood.

Comment: this is not what I have asked. please check my question