# How to get current running app in lollipop version devices?

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am developing app locker application for all the versions. It's working in pre lollipop version but not working in lollipop version.

I am getting all the running application in lollipop version but i want to find which application is opened.

source for running application: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses/

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand, you try to determine current foreground application. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service).

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you the package name of currently running application:

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = "";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
     packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
    } else {
     packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    }
```

Comment: Hii thanks for your answer already i used this solution but  it's working in 5.1 nexus emulator not working in some real devices and 23 version