# Get foreground app API level 21

Tags: android, api, foreground-service, usagestatsmanager

As **ActivityManager.getRunningTasks** is deprecated from API level 21. So I decided to use **UsageStatsManager** instead. But **getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE)** is only available from API level 22. That means I can only get the foreground package name in devices with API level >= 22 and <= 20. What about API 21 devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using UsageStatsManager now to get the foreground app, and I'm running 5.0.1. Even though Android Studio says it is available from 22, it still works.

Using some code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778294/969016