# How to detect when an Android application is minimized?

Tags: android, android-activity, minimize, onpause

How to detect when an Android app goes to the background? 
onPause() or onUserLeaveHint() works but are also called when the orientation is changed or another activity is presented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If orientation changes the app will call  through the life cycle once again that means from oncreate

you can avoid it as well by writing the following to code to the manifest

```
 <activity
      android:name=""
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

this tell the system that when orientation changes or keyboardHidden or screenLayout changes I will handle it by myself no need to re create it.

then write your code on on pause

Comment: Ok happy coding

Comment: this might solve the orientationChange issue, but onPause will still be called when you switch activities and the app is not be minimized..... I'm still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 19):

The marked answer is a workaround for the OP's question.
For the rest of us that are looking for an answer you can achieve this using **Android Architecture Components**

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;

class OurApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onAppBackgrounded() {
        Logger.localLog("APP BACKGROUNDED");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onAppForegrounded() {
        Logger.localLog("APP FOREGROUNDED");
    }
}
```

and remember to update the manifest file. set the `android:name=".OurApplication"` attribute for the `<application>` tag

Comment: Add below dependency for some one who can't use **androidx**: 

`implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() 
   { 
        // When user presses home page
        Log.v(TAG, "Home Button Pressed");
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

For detail : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()

Comment: I need finish activity when app goes to the background. onUserLeaveHint also called when orientation changed. So it doesn't works for me