# how to toast the opened app package name(when I open any app its package name needs to be toast

Tags: java, android, android-toast

In android phone I wish to toast the name of the opened package(app)
Again when I open another app I wish the package name of that particular app is toast.
Also I wish to do all this using service
I would be very thankful for Your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "toast something"

Comment: means to make a toast that something?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Comment: there is no trigger you can use to know when an app is opened unless your app is a launcher app

Comment: Thank You,i could not find exact codes but thankyou so much for reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you need to show package name of any app you open. First, search how to create a broadcast receiver then put this code in it.

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = mgr.getRunningTasks(1); 
     Log.d("topActivity", "Current Running Activity ::"
             + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

     ComponentName component = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
     String packageName = component.getPackageName();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), packageName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Add this permission on your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

To detect if an app is opened , you have to create an intent and fire it when the top activity is changed from your background thread.

Comment: He wants to get his package name, what's the great code for?

Comment: Thank You so much.I am new to android cause of which I dont know how to use broadcast receiver create intent to fire in background thread   can you please add this(broadcast receiver) program too in your previous program.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in your launcher activity

```
 public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    Toast.makeText(this, PACKAGE_NAME , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```