# Android custom Launcher or home screen

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-7.1-nougat

i want to make and android application as home screen/launcher  in which i want to lock or restrict user from using other applications only the limited applications will open which i will allow to use and disabling the home button so that user can not close my home/launcher applications etc. does android nougat and android M allow developers to make this kind off application ? is there is any tutorial or any other guide please suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have made it. Why dont you just install in a 7.0 and see if it still works? If it does not, then post that. And for what version did you originally make?

Comment: `Will this kind of application work` why don't you check it? nobody knows what exactly your app is, only you know. And only you can check it.

Comment: @Oasa well which i made earlier doesn't work so the reason i posted this is asking for there any way to do so ???

Comment: @VladMatvienko okay in simple way i want to make and android launcher application as default launcher which user can not change.

Comment: there should be no way to do that in regullar android, as the user has to have abbility to change his launcher any time he wants. Maybe it is possible in kiosk mode of Android.

Comment: @VladMatvienko it was possible in before android 5.0 version devices. but not working in android 7.0. can you suggest m some links for kiosk mode of android.

Comment: I don't think that it was possible. You shoudl show the code for us to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i have not started new one  yet i am just thinking scenario is like i want to make and android home/launcher application in which after installing in android device. user will be restricted to open application. only limited applications will can be open. example like in my launcher application i was only allowed the facebook application to be use. only facebook application can be open if user click on other application error message should be pop like you can not open this application.

Comment: did you ask uncle goole for `android custom launcher example`?

Comment: @pskink obviously i did. For your kind information stackoverflow in more than google to me.

Comment: so what was wrong in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd link?

Comment: @pskinki can not find the related one.

Comment: @pskink its only giving that how to make android application launcher. but by pressing the home button the user and exit from the application. that what i want to restrict user from opening other application.

Comment: and where is that requirement in your qustion? i dont see any "home button" there... even though after pressing the home button the control is returned to your custom launcher so whats wrong with it?

Comment: @pskink sorry my bad i didn't mentioned that. problem with home button is that it also give user to select the default launcher.

Comment: I have a temporary solution. Add a password to your account and log in as Guest. If you just want one APP to work you can PIN it as well. For a complete KIOSK mode, refer [COSU](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to a kiosk mode application. In my past experience, Kiosk mode applications can be easily made with root privlages(rooted phones) by killing System-UI and re implementing the back and home buttons with floating type buttons. In non rooted phones try setting your homescreen app as the default homescreen(if this is set then every time when user presses home button your app will be launched), then run a service to constantly monitor the app that is currently in foreground(refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4543981/3840909 ). If an undesired app is opened by user then from the service just launch an intent to your homescreen.

Final note: while creating a kiosk mode app make sure you don't allow user to access the Notification drawer, recent apps button, settings app.