# I need to run my app in background

Tags: java, android

Whenever user open any app i need know if application is running on the UI thread. I also need to show a toast of the Package Name of that application.

I have user Activity Manager but it not working as it should. It always shows displayed Launcher.

```
 ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
 ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 pack = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use usage stats to achieve this?

Comment: Got it please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service/30778294#30778294

Comment: but i just use Notification for user visibility but my intent to display as Toast is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as displaying the name of your package you can use PackageManager and `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`

Comment: can you please post some sample code i have using handler       Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (isForeground().equals(packag)) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"camera is open",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });